# The closure of Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, closures

If you have A->B
What is the closure (A->B)+
Is it just A->B ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for trivial functional dependencies as well, then you have stuff like A->A, B->B, AB->A, AB->B, AB->AB, and of course A->B and A->AB. It's easy to see that once there are more than a few attributes, explicitly writing out the closure of a set of FDs becomes unwieldy.

However, there is a polynomial-time algorithm for checking whether an FD X->Y is in F+ for any set of FDs F.